# Which startup file should I use?

Tags: embedded, arm, stm32

Bundled with "Standard peripheral library" for my STM32F2 chip, are "startup" files `startup_stm32f2xx.s`. There is actually 5 different startup files, in five different folders:

MDK-ARM, TrueSTUDIO, iar, gcc_ride7, arm

I am assuming that each startup file is specific to the IDE used. I am *not* using an IDE. I simply use OpenOCD and GDB. Which of the 5 startup files should I use? What is the difference between the files?

Comment: Hey there, @Randomblue, I've also decided to go down the yagarto/openocd route, although I'm using Eclipse to tie everything together. I'd be really keen to talk to you about your experience, as I'm having a bad time getting everything working well. aaaidan at gee-male dot com!

Comment: I could help you out here. What exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The startup files are particular to a compiler, not particular to an IDE. The files are all fairly close, and my guess is you're using GCC, so the gcc_ride7 is probably closest to what you need.